# Nginx Sites Available configuration

Tags: nginx

In nginx folder, I am seeing this folder with 777 permissions which I can't access in SFTP. Is this normal?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbvjfhk8h7acnkp/Screenshot%202016-09-07%2017.12.16.png?dl=0

I don't understand that that little arrow on top of the folder means. Sorry for being a noob!

Answer (score 1):

this is a symbolic link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link. I know that thanks to the first character of the permissions.

Check if the folder it is pointing at exists.

Moreover, in a typical nginx configuration:

- sites-available and sites-enabled are directories
- you put one config file for each website in sites-available
- nginx includes config files that are in sites-enabled (this is configured in nginx.conf file)

This allows to configure website without serving it. To serve it you just create a link (in sites-enabled) pointing to it's conf file (which is in sites-available). To stop serving it, you remove the link. (nginx have to be reloaded)

http://nginx.org/en/docs/

That "moreover" part seems a bit irrelevant? Tell me, I'll remove it.

Comment: hmm.. i am not sure if it exists. i guess that's what the fileicon in filezilla means ?

Comment: Can you try with another ftp client? Simple and fast test. I guess that you have only remote access to the folders?